# Find the integral solutions for |X|+|Y|+|Z|=10

Tags: combinatorics

I have worked out the following solution using my teachers instructions.

We know, when mode is involved, value of same positive or negative integer is always equal to the value of positive integer; i.e., |2|=2 & |-2|=2.

Now,
When none of the bins are empty, i.e.,|X|+|Y|+|Z|=10 where X,Y,Z≠0
Since, All the items are identical an all the bins are distinct,

Total number of solutions for all the bins =(2C1)(2C1)(2C1)×((n-1)C(k-1))=8×(92)=8×36=288

When only one bin is empty value of k becomes 2,

Total number of solutions for two bins =(2C1)(2C1)(3C1)×((n-1)C(k-1))=12×(9C1)=12×9=108

When two of the bins are empty value of k becomes 1,

Total number of solutions for one bin =(2C1)(3C2)×((n-1)C(k-1))=6×(9C0)=6×1=6

⸫ Total number of integral solutions for |X|+|Y|+|Z|=10 is 288+108+6 = 402.

However, the solution above is quite cumbersome and I tried to find an alternative method, like the following:
(2C1)(12C2)93C1) which equals to 396. What am I doing wrong here?

I have also looked into the similar thread in this site, where it states that the solution is 4×10^2+2 but found the explanation behind the equation beyond me. At least for now.

Lastly How do I write Binomial Coefficient in my questions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question

Comment: If you type `\binom{n}{k}`, you will obtain $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Why do you believe there should necessarily be an approach which utilizes a single application of rule-of-product?  By the very nature of the question, not all outcomes have the same number of variations.  This screams to me that it needs to be handled by cases.

Comment: As for it being cumbersome... if you were to deal with a problem with a thousand variables, sure, I can agree that it is a tad cumbersome... but in such a case we would have generalized each term and expressed this as a sum and let a computer finish the arithmetic for us.  For only three, this is hardly that cumbersome, $2^3\cdot 36 + 2^2\cdot 27 + 2\cdot 3$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222690/number-of-integral-solutions-for-x-y-z-10)